# Find the set of complex number where the given function is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is to find the set of all complex number where $f(z)=x^3y^2+ix^2y^3$ (where $z=x+iy$) is differentiable.
And i tried using CR equation and I found that the origin (x=y=0) is the only point satisfying the CR equation. Is this correct?

And how should I check whether it is differentiable at origin? From what i understand, CR equation is necessary but not sufficient to show a function is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

For functions with $C^1$ (or even real differentiable) real and and imaginary part, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are indeed sufficient conditions for complex differentiability. Your function is smooth enough for this.

On the other hand you have miscalculated your solutions. With $u = x^3y^2$ and $v=x^2y^3$ you get
$$
u'_x = 3x^2y^2, \qquad u'_y = 2x^3y, \qquad v'_x = 2xy^3, \qquad v'_y = 3x^2y^2
$$
so $u'_x = v'_y$ is *always* satisfied. The second CR equation is
$$
2x^3y = -2xy^3 \iff 2xy(x^2+y^2) = 0
$$
which is satisfied for $x=0$ *or* $y=0$.